# Is it safe to have the next value of a cryptographic nonce be pre-computed based on past values?

Tags: cryptography, libsodium, nonce

The server shall only need to use pseudo-random generator to create the first nonce upon initialization and this value the client shall be made aware of. This nonce shall be used on first encryption request and then the server calculates the next value of the nonce based on certain attributes of that response an ability that both client and server is able to do. The second encryption request will use the updated value of the nonce and so on. This is like how initialization vector works in other solutions.

Since nonce are publicly visible values, and base on initial research it's public visibility has no effect on security, my question here is only with regards to the generation of chain of nonce values rather than randomly. The benefit is it shall form a link between client and server in the encryption requests.

I am using libsodium crypto system.

Comment: how will you pre-compute it?

Comment: `xor` it with last result of encrypt request. Whatever the way is, both the client and the server can do.

Comment: This strongly depends on the specific cryptosystem that relies on the nonce, and the strength of your pseudo-random number generator (what is your source of entropy?) The main question here is: why are you inventing a system at all? What are your security requirements, and can you make use of an existing construction? I'm particularly concerned about "and base on initial research…" Precisely what system are you relying on, and what are the security requirements of its nonce? "Nonce" is a generic term, and the precise requirements are dependent on the specifics of the crypto-system.

Comment: I addaed the crypto system in the tag section as libsodium. I updated question, to include the crypto system

Comment: So the context as to why let me explain. Protobuf is used. I don't want to edit the protobuf definition to insert the nonce. As I stated, no PRG is used except on unit. The rest are deterministic chain of values that both can calculate. I don't think that I'm re-invenring stuff if the method of nonce generation is clarified

Comment: libsodium is a library, not a system. Do you mean that you're using their Secret Box format (which is a full system), or are you building something else out of the primitives they offer? When I discussed the PRG, that's the one I'm talking about. How is it seeded? Poorly seeded nonces are a common source of security problems. (If the server generating the random seed is a full computer in a data center, then it's generally fine; the concern is when the generator is an embedded device.)

Comment: The short of this is that for certain systems, even pretty common systems, Woodstock's answer is completely correct, and this is in fact a normal way to implement nonce-based systems. But there are many cases where it is not true, and it depends on the details of the system. It also matters what "the server calculates the next value of the nonce based on certain attributes of that response" means. "Certain attributes of that response" can easily lead you to short nonce cycles if not designed carefully, which would destroy the security of the systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nonce doesn't have to be secret just random. i.e. **not reused**. It's fine once you can satisfy this. I suggest a hash ratchet of the nonce.

Comment: Who in best practice, generates the nonce is it client or server?

Comment: This completely depends on the crypto-system. Some nonces have stronger requirements, such as not being predictable, which is more strict than not being reused. This cannot be evaluated in the absence of a specific crypto system.

Comment: Some things getting clearer. A nonce doesn't need to be random. For example, a counting integer from 1 to infinity can be a valid nonce and it is not random.

Comment: Yes I agree it depends on context. That’s fine for a transport session. But for arbitrary use of secret box random nonce is needed.